# I cannot upload photos on S3 bucket of Pix4d API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, nestjs

I am working on a small project which is based on PIX4D API. The project is in nest.js for backend and react typescript for frontend. I have done everything like creating token, creating project, getting aws credentials for that project but when i am trying to upload photos on s3, while i have put the correct credentials i am getting error for authorization. There is no source for this solution.

The following method is on nestjs and it is for uploading photos on s3:

```
async uploadPhotoS3(fileData: Buffer): Promise<any> { 

 try{
    const {id} = await this.projectService.createProject({ name: 'firstproject' });
    const awsConfig = await this.awsService.getCredentials(id);
   

    console.log(awsConfig);

    
    const s3 = {
      accessKeyId: awsConfig.access_key,
      secretKey: awsConfig.secret_key,
      sessionToken: awsConfig.session_token,
      bucket: awsConfig.bucket,
      key: awsConfig.key,
      region: awsConfig.region
    }
    
    
    // Prepare the request options
    const requestOptions = {
      host: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/${s3.bucket}`,
      url: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/${s3.bucket}/${s3.key}`,
      path: `/${s3.key}`,
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
       // 'Authorization': `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${accKey}/20230606/${region}/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=${awsConfig.Signature}`
      },
      service: 's3',
      region: s3.region, 
      data: fileData,
      body: fileData,
    };

    

    // Sign the request using aws4
    const signedRequest = AWS4.sign(requestOptions, {
      accessKeyId: s3.accessKeyId ,
      secretAccessKey: s3.secretKey,
      sessionToken: s3.sessionToken,
    });

    console.log(signedRequest);

    
    delete signedRequest.headers['Host'];

 

   const response = await axios({
      ...signedRequest,
    url:`https://s3.${s3.region}.amazonaws.com/${s3.bucket}/${s3.key}`,   
       data: requestOptions.body
  });
 
    console.log(response);

  return response;
  } catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Does someone has experience with pix4d api and s3 bucket?

The link for pix4d api is this:
https://developer.pix4d.com/cloud-api/index.html

The error that i am getting is probably on the response line. The error:
[axios 403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeBdp.png)

Comment: Please include the _exact_ error message you are receiving and tell us which line of code is generating the error.

Comment: i just updated and insert the error screenshot

Comment: A 403 error means that the credentials used do not have sufficient permissions. This is either because the Access Key and Secret Key are using does not have sufficient permissions, or something is going wrong with the signing code you are using. Have you considered using the [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/) instead?

Comment: Yes, i also used the aws-sdk, to check if it works and it shows me invalidAccessKey error. When i am doing the process on postman it works perfect.